# Dlist: using stableLinearRemove in a foreach loop

Tags: d

I've written the following code but it doesn't give the correct result (for instance if you enter [-1,-1], it returns [-1,-1,-1].

```
import std.stdio, std.range, std.container, std.algorithm;

DList!T strandSort(T)(DList!T list) {
    static DList!T merge(DList!T left, DList!T right) {
        DList!T res;
        while (!left.empty && !right.empty) {
            if (left.front <= right.front) {
                res.insertBack(left.front);
                left.removeFront();
            } else {
                res.insertBack(right.front);
                right.removeFront();
            }
        }
        res.insertBack(left[]);
        res.insertBack(right[]);
        return res;
    }

    DList!T result, sorted;

    while (!list.empty) {
        sorted.clear();
        sorted.insertBack(list.front);
        list.removeFront();
        foreach (item; list) {
            if (sorted.back <= item) {
                sorted.insertBack(item);
                list.stableLinearRemove(list[].find(item).take(1)));
            }
        }
        result = merge(sorted, result);
    }

    return result;
}

void main() {
    auto lst = DList!int([-1,-1]);
    foreach (e; strandSort(lst))
        writef("%d ", e);
}
```

Sometimes, the stableLinearRemove doesn't remove the item from the list. The question is, is it a bug in my code, or in Phobos?

See also the discusion on [Rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Talk%3aSorting_algorithms/Strand_sort)

**Edit**: I suspect it's caused by removeFront. It doesn't set the prev node pointer of the second node to null when the first node is removed. When the item to be removed from the list by linearRemove happens to be the first node, it won't be removed. The remove function checks "before" and "after" nodes and the "before" is still set. If I write it like this, it does work:

```
if (sorted.back <= item) {
    sorted.insertBack(item);
    if (list.front == item)
        list.removeFront();
    else 
        list.stableLinearRemove(list[].find(item).take(1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug in Phobos, but rather a gotcha. You shouldn't rely on linearRemove to remove an element if it might be the first in the list. Check for that first and use removeFront. Is also more efficient.

In the case above, a better solution would be to copy the list:

```
DList!T result, sorted, leftover;

while (!list.empty) {
    leftover.clear();
    sorted.clear();
    sorted.insertBack(list.front);
    list.removeFront();
    foreach (item; list) {
        if (sorted.back <= item)
            sorted.insertBack(item);
        else
            leftover.insertBack(item);
    }
    result = merge(sorted, result);
    list = leftover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is definitely a bug in removeFront.

Though I might point out that removing iterated elements via foreach is not going to be efficient even if it is supposed to be valid. you need a handle to the range. consider:

```
auto rng = list[];
while(!rng.empty) {
    auto item = rng.front;
    if(sorted.back <= item) {
        sorted.insertBack(item);
        auto rng2 = rng.save();
        rng.popFront();
        list.stableLinearRemove(rng2.take(1)); // O(1) removal!
    }else{
        rng.popFront();
    }
}
```

Ah, well. Above probably doesn't work in light of the bug.